# Azure Notification Hub doesn't work with enterprise release

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-notificationhub

When I run my application on my iPad from Xcode, everything works fine. But when I do enterprise release, push notification does not show up.

**This is my code for registration:**

```
func registerForAzurePushNotifications() {
    let connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xyz="
    let hubName = "POC"

    // Creates with alert, badge and sound
    let hubOptions = MSNotificationHubOptions(withOptions: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
    // Starts MSNotificationHub SDK
    MSNotificationHub.start(connectionString: connectionString, hubName: hubName, options: hubOptions!)
    // Get the Device identifier
    var deviceTag = ""
    // Creates tags with type_value format
    if let id = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString{
       deviceTag = id
    }
    MSNotificationHub.addTags([deviceTag]) 
}
```

**Code for catching the notification**

```
func notificationHub(_ notificationHub: MSNotificationHub, didReceivePushNotification notification: MSNotificationHubMessage) {
    let title = notification.title ?? ""
    let body = notification.body ?? ""
    print("Notification received: title:\"\(title)\" body:\"\(body)\"")
}
```

**Azure Portal Response**

[image: Azure Portal Response]

Any opinions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you selected production mode in the notification hub?

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. It was in Sandbox mode. I will try again

Comment: @Paulw11 After changing it to Production mode, the push notification test is failing. "The Notification could not be delivered due to an unknown error"

Comment: Are you using token or certificate authentication?

Comment: I am using certificate for authentication.

Comment: In XCode, run the app on a physical iOS device (push notifications will not work in the simulator).
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-push-apple-apns-secure-notification#run-the-application

Also, see dropped notification reasons - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Comment: Any update on this? I use a cross-platform app and works on android but not ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload certificates for both Debug and Release mode.